# MHL screen becomes static anytime a new app is loaded

Tags: htc-one, hdmi, external-display, mhl, gpu

I have an HTC One m7 that I use to stream Netflix with over an MHL HDMI cable to a touch screen.

When I was running ViperOne 7.0.1 I would only occasionally see this and it would regain the video feed after becoming static. It is random and not repeatable by any particular steps.

Now I am running Cyanogenmod M12 (latest snapshot) and any time I open Netflix, I get permanent static until I unplug and re-plug the MHL cable. Also any time a new app loads or a new Netflix video loads, I'll get static until pulling and replugging in the cable.

Given that it works fine in one ROM and not so well in the other, what is the missing link to getting this to work reliably? Is it the kernel? What can I do to figure out the problem?

Comment: Sounds like it might be a problem in the EGL driver. If that's so, there's not much you can do to debug it since you won't have the source.

Comment: Could I find out which EGL driver I have now vs the on I had before? (First I've heard of EGL)

Comment: It might say in the log, but it depends how it was compiled. You might need to check with the ROM author. It might even be the same driver binary in both cases, but it's broken because the versions of other parts of the system have changed.

Comment: Is the EGL driver typically built into the system, kernel, or somewhere else in particular? Any chance I could flash in a new one?

Comment: More realistically, what logs would I want to look for?

Comment: It relies on userspace and kernel components, and needs to be integrated with other parts of Android such as SurfaceFlinger. Even if you had the source it'd probably be a week's work. As for logs, you need the `logcat`. I don't know what kind of log tag you might be looking for because I don't have that phone.